# HTTP/2 Response Header in Java

Tags: java, http-headers, http2

Is there already a way to get the HTTP/2 response header in Java? I've tried to search in some libraries like URLConnection, Undertow or even Jetty, but without success.

P.S.: I'm using JDK 1.7 on my Java Project.

Other thing, the response header of the HTTP/2 is like this?

```
 GET / HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.example.com
 Connection: Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings
 Upgrade: h2c
 HTTP2-Settings: <base64url encoding of HTTP/2 SETTINGS payload>
```

Is there any website who use this version already?

My main goal is to know if a website use the HTTP/2 version or not, is there a way to know this without need to read the response header in a Java Project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP/2 websites typically use TLS, because browsers only support HTTP/2 over TLS.

The method you are trying to use is the HTTP/1.1 upgrade to HTTP/2 which very few sites - if any at all - support.

Your snippet of code represent a **request**, not a response.
If the upgrade is successful, the HTTP/2 server sends back a 101 response in HTTP/1.1 format *and* the response to the `GET` request in HTTP/2 format. This is specified in [RFC 7540, section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-3.2).

In order to achieve what you want, i.e. to know if a website supports HTTP/2, you have to try to connect using HTTP/2 + TLS. If the connection succeeds, you know HTTP/2 is supported. If it fails, it's not supported.

For Jetty (disclaimer, I'm the HTTP/2 module maintainer), you have to use JDK 8, and the code will look like this:

```java
// Setup.
HTTP2Client http2Client = new HTTP2Client();
SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2(http2Client), sslContextFactory);
httpClient.start();

// Does webtide.com support HTTP/2 ?
ContentResponse response = httpClient.GET("https://webtide.com/");
// No errors, yes it supports HTTP/2 !
```

If you get a response without errors, you are on HTTP/2, otherwise the server does not support HTTP/2.

Remember that for that code to work, you have to use JDK 8 and the proper ALPN boot jar in the bootclasspath, as specified [here](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html).

Comment: Apache's HTTP/2 module supports h2c, so that should - at least in theory - allow quite a few servers to enable it.

Comment: Thank you very much @sbordet, I've already installed the JDK 8, but ALPN boot jar looks complicated for me. I forgot to say but I'm using my  project on Netbeans and from what I look for, it needs to install a plug in to use Jetty. 

I would like to only download a jar available on internet and use the code inside them, like the URLConnection from the package java.net.URLConnection. Is there a jar (ready to use) available for Jetty to install on my Java Project on Netbeans?

Is there a way to do this using this Apache's HTTP/2 module or from any other technology?

Comment: I'm trying to use Jetty on netbeans, but I'm not finding any good jar to use this code...

Comment: You just need to configure NetBeans to add the ALPN jar to the bootclasspath when you run your application. There is no plugin needed, just configure NetBeans.

Comment: This answer now needs update for the JDK11 HttpClient .. http://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html